# Removing GRUB from sda from Mac Internet Recovery

Tags: macos, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, bootloader

I tried to make a bootable Ubuntu DVD on my MAC. This lead to messing up my bootloader which I have been unable to fix.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3109456?tstart=0

One person states

> Boot OSX and in the terminal write:
>   mkdir mnt ; sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 mnt
>   Will show a new drive EFI
>   Open this drive and open the folder EFI
>   Inside you will have the folders APPLE and UBUNTU
>   Just delete the UBUNTU folder

So I keep reading and see

> When in -Recovery From Internet- it is impossible to use mkdir, but
>   you can "cd /tmp" and mount it there.

So I haven't been able to figure out how to mount disk0s1 in the /tmp. If someone could please show me the commands to get into the EFI Folder so I can delete the Ubuntu folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34639609/how-to-get-rid-of-grub-and-restore-my-windows-back/34870534#34870534

Answer (score 0):

I assume the link means you can do something like:

```
mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /tmp/
```

then

```
cd /tmp
```

and you should see the APPLE and UBUNTU directories.  I am not in Recovery Mode now so I can't try that, but deleting UBUNTU from there may help you.

This page:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html

is what I use when I want to install Linux on a Mac, and has a lot of useful explanation about EFI booting on Mac machines.  I have had good luck with SuperGrub2 when I've gotten in trouble:

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/